# Send all records from SQL Server table though send mail task in body

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I am trying to send all the table records in email body though send mail task

My flow:

1. I uses SQL execute task to fetch the rows from table and stored in an object
2. Uses for each loop container and in that I use a script task to store the rows in an EmailMessage body
3. I used Send mail task to send the email

I am only getting last records of the table in the message body.

Please guide me how to send all the table data at once in a message body

[Actaul flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZP6W.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bApZr.png)

Comment: show us some of your code.  It sounds like you could be resetting the MessageBody variable you are using within you script task or perhaps you are exceeding maximum lenghts of the variable or the send maild task message body or????   Another approach would be to use the entire recordset in a ScriptTask rather than a foreach loop and build your message body there and send via .net email message.....  The added advantage to the latter approach is you can use HTML if desired.

Comment: Hey Matt please see my attached script task code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would take a slightly different approach and recurse the recordset directly in the script task but this looks like it would work too.  I would guess that your problem is that you **overwrite** `User::EmailMessage` at every iteration.  You say you get last few records but looking at your code I would think you will get 1 unless you uncomment the IF `(varcollection == string.empty)` in which case you might get more.

Anyway, the main offending problem is

```
varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value = header;
```

That resets your EmailMessage body to the header row any time it is called.

Edit: Adding as per your comment to reset message at every new shipment number. Add another package variable PrevShippingNum which will hold the previous looped number to test if it is the same or has changed.  Make sure that this variable is listed as ReadWriteVariable to the script task.  then modify your script to include something like this:

```
        Dts.VariableDispenser.GetVariables(ref varCollection);

        bool newMessage = (varCollection["User::PrevShippingNum"].value != varCollection["User::ShppingNum"].value) ? true : false;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value.ToString()) || newMessage)
        {
            varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value = string.Format("{0}........");
        }

        varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value += string.Format("{0}......");
```

The positive about this is you can also use your new variable as a constraint to determine when to send email task.

**A different Approach:**

Note pretty big edit to add new sub to take care of sending emails per ShippingNum:

Way I would proceed pass the recordset variable you are using to a script task and let it do the email message building.  Just to be clear this is to replace your foreach loop!  here is some code adapted from one of my solutions:

Add Reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`

Add following namespaces:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

    private void Main()
    {
        //using System.Data.OleDb;
        OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oleAdapter.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables["User::OleDbRecordSetVar"].Value);

        //build header row
        string headerRow = string.Format("{0}........", "ShippingNum ....");

        //get distinct shippingNums
        var shippingNums = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                            select (int)dr["ShppingNum"]).Distinct();

        //Now Build the Differnt Emails
        foreach (var num in shippingNums)
        {
            string emailBody = headerRow;
            List<DataRow> emailLines = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                              where (int)dr["ShippingNum"] == num
                              select dr).ToList<DataRow>();

            foreach (DataRow line in emailLines)
            {
                emailBody += string.Format("{0}....", line["ColumnName1"].ToString(), line["ColumnName2"].ToString());
            }

            SendEmail(emailBody);

        }

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    private void SendEmail(string messageBody)
    { 
        //get the smtp server address from the SSIS connection manger
        ConnectionManager smtpConnectionManager = Dts.Connections["Name Of SMTP Connection Manager"];
        //note this is for trusted authentication if you want to use a username and password you will have to do some discovery
        SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(smtpConnectionManager.Properties["SmtpServer"].GetValue(smtpConnectionManager).ToString());

        MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
        email.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
        email.IsBodyHtml = false; //change to true if you send html
                                  //can hard code addresses if you desire I use variables to make it more flexible
        email.From = new MailAddress(Dts.Variables["User::FromAddress"].Value.ToString());
        email.To.Add(Dts.Variables["User::ToAddress"].Value.ToString());
        email.Body = messageBody;
        emailClient.Send(email);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, I am getting data from the table but i want only distinct shipments for each mail. when i run the package the first email getting correct but in next iteration previos shipment also coming . how i can reset varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value = varCollection["User::EmailMessage"].Value + message whenver shipment number is different,Please see the ressult data

Comment: which version are you using the foreach like you were doing or the method I suggested?  Either way you will have to maintain the previous iterations shipment number as well as the current and compare them.  I feel this is easier in my method but if you add a new package variable and maintain via your script you can still do it in the other method too.  which ever way you tell me I will alter the script to show you. cheers

Comment: I used prevous script task method not you mentioned

Comment: I actually edited both methods I think the second is a lot cleaner and you can dump everything from your flow except the SQL task if you use that direction.

Comment: Hi Matt can you please tell me how can i get this variable    User::OleDbRecordSetVar  i have done same as you told but error showing with this is unknown variable

Comment: You have to create it.  I thought you already had a recordset variable from your flow being used in your for each loop?  If so use that variable name there.  If you haven't use a dataflow before the script task. Add source to get the data you want and choose recordset as the destination storing it into a package variable.

Comment: also make sure that you add it to the ReadOnlyVariable list in the Script Task

Comment: hey bro i am getting one more problem whenver i am going to debug script task then it will show black screen i cant able to debug

Comment: An error has occured while loading getting started information.Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: That's pretty vague, can you update your post with the remote server error and where you are getting it?  As far as debugging you can try inserting some breakpoints to step through the script and find your issue. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140033(v=sql.110).aspx  Also post the code you are using at this point

Comment: hey in the script task i make one line as break point ,the break point also show,but when i run the package it executes the script and goes to the script task inside but there nothing information showing only blank screen is showing,previously it was working fine. on the right side of the corner the error message show An error has occured while loading getting started information.Unable to connect to the remote server

Comment: it sounds like maybe having an issue connecting to the smtp server?  you can also use messagebox.show() and/or throw new exception placed throughout the code to create your own breakpoint/notification to see at which point the script fails. Can you post the code you are using now so I can look at it otherwise I really am blind to trying to help you troubleshoot.